# Running Renderscript on single core

Tags: android, renderscript

1. I am learning renderscript, I have a doubt regarding what will happen if renderscript code will run on a single CPU core, will there be a performance benefit?
2. Also in root function function we have two unit32_t argument which enables you to access the some coordinate but I am confused about what location it points to and what is the need of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Why do you think it will run on a "single CPU core"? We have been running RS on all CPU cores since the very beginning, so you are confused.
2) In a kernel (like "root"), the two uint32_t arguments x and y are used to give you the index of the cell that is currently being computed. For instance, if you have a 1024 x 768 Allocation, x and y will vary between 0-1023 and 0-767 respectively. Each pair (corresponding to 1 cell in the computation) will only be executed once.

It is useful if you also need to access a global variable using rsGetElementAt_*(). An example of that would be a blend, where you need to read from 2 inputs (we only provide a single input in RS today), so you would get one of your pixels to read from that input, and you can read the other pixel using rsGetElementAt_*().

Comment: Thanks for your answer my question was what if RS code runs on a cpu with only a single core

Comment: Even on a single core, RS is faster for data processing than the corresponding Java code will be. It is also usually faster than NDK C/C++ code, because it can take advantage of NEON and other processor specific features without having to have a fallback path that doesn't.